# Binary Operation on Negative integer

Tags: java, binary

System.out.print((-15) & (-1 >> 1));

Why does the above code return -15?

Shouldn't it set the MSB to 0 as the bitmask is (-1 >> 1) which is 01111111

I was expecting a positive integer but it returns -15. The logic is unclear. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

According to [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the
> leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on
> sign extension.

So >> keeps the sign and you probably nedd an >>>